# How can I use Emacs to edit questions, answers, and comments here?

Tags: major-mode, integration

## Emacs as a StackExchange client?

How can I use Emacs to edit questions, answers, and comments here on the Emacs Stack Exchange site?

Broadly, what possible methods exist?

### Kill and yank

This works, but the method is so cumbersome that it's not worth it for short posts or even medium-length posts.

### Browser plugin

There is a relatively well know browser plugin for Firefox that lets your push the text content of any `<textarea>` back and forth between the editor of your choice.  I presume it works via temp files and I haven't evaluated it.  [Using the plugin with emacs has been discussed on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383986/emacs-mode-for-stack-overflows-markdown/10386560#10386560).  I don't use Chrome any more.

### Stack Exchange API

Something called [Stack Exchange Mode for Emacs](https://stackapps.com/questions/3950/stack-exchange-mode-for-emacs) exists.  I have not evaluated it.  [The source](https://github.com/vermiculus/stack-mode) isn't too stale, but the project is obviously not completed.

### Other options?

I seek suggestions!

## Motivations

Regardless of what method is used to edit questions, answers, and comments in emacs, I am sure that doing so will enable us to do some common tasks with ease:

- Adhere to [conventions](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conventions).  Something like `M-x record-keystrokes-and-write-them-out-as-markdown RET C-x C-s C-g RET` ...might yield:

  `C-x C-s C-g`
- Ask what an error message means: `M-x post-region-on-emacs-se-as-question RET` ...

Comment: I deliberately didn't mention in my question that I'm a Linux user.  Should I?  Of course, I use SE most often when I'm at work, where I do all my internet browsing in a Windows host and emacs work in a Linux VM...

Comment: Chrome Edit-with-emacs is not buggy for me...

Comment: Would the user who deleted his or her Answer consider putting it back?  There was a useful elisp function in there.  Do unaccepted answers count against a user in some way I don't know about?

Comment: @daveloyall: I'm interested in what problems you had with the Chrome textarea solution (**disclosure** I am the maintainer of Edit with Emacs). I quite happily edit StackExchange posts with it and markdown-mode.

Comment: @stsquad Well, I am not sure.  I don't have it installed anymore, so I'm not sure what version I used. Ok, I did a little digging (only a little) and I found that many of the subject lines here https://github.com/stsquad/emacs_chrome/issues sound like the kind of thing that I encountered. Basically if the javascript on some site can make it not work, it's not what I'm looking for... Anyway, I stopped using Chrome when an update permanently disabled non-web-store extensions, like the little ones I wrote locally.

Comment: You say "I don't use Chrome anymore." Do you mean "I don't use Firefox anymore"? I ask because you point to a Firefox plugin but then mention Chrome.

Comment: @b4hand That line was edited.  It used to say something about not liking the common Chrome extension that serves the same purpose.  I edited it out due to peer pressure!

Comment: `sx.el` is in a usable state now.  Some bugs are being worked out with byte-compilation, but the project works out-of-the-box (after authentication -- necessary to use the API) on 24.3.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

See the [Stack Exchange for Emacs](https://github.com/vermiculus/sx.el/) project. From their page:

> SX will be a full featured Stack Exchange mode for GNU Emacs 24+.
>   Using the official API, we aim to create a more versatile experience
>   for the Stack Exchange network within Emacs itself.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Artur Malabarba has promised to write a mode for it, see: https://twitter.com/bruceconnor/status/520692859109117952 I would recommend holding him to it :)

Comment: @Malabarba I'm holding you to it! :)  ...In fact, if this idea had a repo backing it, I'd be very tempted to accept it as an answer.  Not that I'm the sole source of internet points or anything...

Comment: I'll stick to it. :-) current ETA is around Christmas.

Comment: Right now this is almost a link-only answer. If you would like to add a couple of screenshots we could even include them in the readme.

Comment: @Malabarba Hi Malabarba. I'd love to but on my system, after `(require 'sx-load)`, the mini-buffer displays "zlib library not found". I'm on Emacs 24.4.1 on Windows.

Comment: Moved the answer regarding @Malabarba 's creation of a mode to a comment on the mode in question (`sx.el`).

Comment: How have I not seen this Q? :D Interestingly, the package works out-of-the-box on 24.3.  @dharmatech -- would you mind [posting that as an issue](https://github.com/vermiculus/sx.el/issues/new)?

Comment: Wow, just read this, installed sx.el from melpa, ran it and here I am writing a comment using it. Fantastic!

Comment: Malabarba is awesome.

Answer (score 11):

[`edit-server`](https://github.com/stsquad/emacs_chrome) might be of some help. It lets you edit any text field inside Chrome with Emacs and then send the text back to the browser with minimum effort. Not exactly what you wanted, but its an improvement.

Comment: when you say edit-server to you mean the plugin that works with Edit with Emacs in Chrom(ium) based browsers?

Comment: @stsquad Yes. This one https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/edit-with-emacs/ljobjlafonikaiipfkggjbhkghgicgoh

Answer (score 8):

I'm using `w3m` to submit this answer from within Emacs.  The StackExchange sites don't look very nice in w3m, but submitting forms works just fine.  (I've not been able to submit an answer with the new `eww` browser.)

I don't recommend actually doing this, because it seems rather painful compared to using a regular browser with a Emacs-like bindings (e.g. keysnail for Firefox).

**EDIT**: I had to solve a captcha to submit my answer.  Unfortunately, no captcha was shown in the w3m buffer, so I had to visit the captcha URL in a traditional browser.

Answer (score 5):

I have always found kill and yank to be sufficient, but I do have a stackoverflow specific copy function I use.

```
(defun copy-el-for-so (beg end)
  "copy region and format for SO."
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((text (buffer-substring-no-properties beg end)))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert "<!--Language: lang-lisp -->\n")
      (replace-string "\n" "\n    " nil (point)
                      (progn
                        (insert "\n" text)
                        (point)))
      (copy-region-as-kill (point-min) (point-max))
      (message "copied"))))
```

Which takes things like:

```
(defun process-exit-code-and-output (program &rest args)
  "Run PROGRAM with ARGS and return the exit code and output in a list."
  (with-temp-buffer
    (list (apply 'call-process program nil (current-buffer) nil args)
          (buffer-string))))
```

and turn them into:

```
<!--Language: lang-lisp -->

    (defun process-exit-code-and-output (program &rest args)
      "Run PROGRAM with ARGS and return the exit code and output in a list."
      (with-temp-buffer
        (list (apply 'call-process program nil (current-buffer) nil args)
              (buffer-string))))
```

---

Alternatively, I find the [Edit With Emacs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/edit-with-emacs/ljobjlafonikaiipfkggjbhkghgicgoh?hl=en) chrome extensions to be very nice.

Comment: I'd suggest Edit With Emacs as separate answer. And I find it nice too, and not buggy.

Answer (score 5):

[Keysnail](https://github.com/mooz/keysnail) implements Emacs keybindings for Firefox.  It also serves as a platform for plug-ins, extending the architecture of Firefox in a distinctively Emacsesque fashion.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that there is a plugin called K2Emacs for Keysnail, that let's you edit textareas in an external program (by default Emacs).

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [Firemacs](https://github.com/kazu-yamamoto/Firemacs) and have been very happy with it. It is a firefox extension which gives you emacs keybinding. It supports many keybindings including kill and yank.

It can be installed from [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firemacs/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Firefox** add-on
[It's All Text](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/its-all-text/).
This will add a tiny "edit" button to the bottom of any text area.
Clicking it (or using a hot-key, default `C-S-v`) fires up Emacs with
the content in a temporary buffer.  Write the buffer (repeatedly) and
the text area updates.

My config for it is simply setting *Editor* to `/usr/bin/emacsclient`.

Comment: This no longer works in newer firefox versions, posted updated answer - https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/56122/2418

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox 57+ [Textern](https://github.com/jlebon/textern) works well (writing on Firefox 74).